# Javascript time-based rendering and animating

Tags: javascript, html, time

I've looked all over Stackoverflow but I can't seem to figure out how time-based rendering works. 
I'm currently using the `setInterval` method but I've heard that it's bad since it's frame-based.

I basically want to be able to move the player across the screen using time-based loops.

This is what I use to render but I'm pretty sure it's not time based.

```
setInterval(function() {

ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height); //clear canvas

renderImage("background.png",0,0); //background

//player
renderSheet(
    "player.png", //image
    Math.floor(player.weight/10)*player.width, //horizontal index
    player.equip*player.height, //vertical index
    player.width, //player width
    player.height, //player height
    player.x, //player x
    player.y, //player y
    player.width, //player width
    player.height //player height
);
},1000/frames);
```

and this is how I handle movement:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) { //key pressed
var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); //turn key pressed into a readable string
if(key == "A") player.dir = -1;
if(key == "D") player.dir = 1;  
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); //turn key pressed into a     readable string
if(key == "A") player.dir = 0;
if(key == "D") player.dir = 0;
}
setInterval(function() {
player.x+= 4*player.dir; //move player

},1000/frames);
```

Please help clarify how time-based movement works and how to implement it! :)

Comment: What do you mean by time based? You want the character to move from A to B in x seconds or something?

Comment: http://acko.net/blog/animate-your-way-to-glory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time-based movement you need the time elapsed since last frame (`delta`) and a speed in pixels per time. (The `delta` value should be accessible from anywhere inside your game.)

To get the time (in seconds) since last frame you do the following (Assuming `Game` is your global Game object):

```
Game.now = Date.now();
Game.delta = Game.now - Game.past/1000
Game.past = Game.now;
```

The `delta` value you can multiply which each speed of different objects to get the traveled distance.

```
var distance = Game.delta * Object.speed;
Object.positionX += distance;
```

Call the function which get's called each frame via `window.requestAnimationFrame` for smoother animations. Inside your `frame` function you should call the `update` and `render` function.

The `update` function usally updates all your game objects which have changed and the `render` function should do things like `redrawing` the canvas.

Comment: I assumed you're coding a game? So you have some global object like `window.Game = window.Game || {}` to access global properties in any component of the game. (`Game` is just the name, you can name it whatever you want to)

Comment: In what function (if in any) should I create the global variable's "now, delta and past"?

Comment: In your gameLoop (`frame`) for example: `frame() { Game.now = Date.now();/* ... update delta and past */ update(); render(); Game.animFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(frame)}`